# How do I import packages with Pyscript? Following examples leads only to failure

Tags: python, pyscript, pyodide

I'm trying to create a page on Pyscript.com. My config looks like this:

```
    <py-config>
        packages = [
        "pandas",
        "ast",
        "re"]
        
        [[fetch]]
        from = 'https://rstory.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/Qmakqr9oKVNcNtdhjkLBc4AuJv3731KKkrCkndLSPvDwjz'
    </py-config>
```

Running this raises the following error: "(PY1001): Unable to install package(s) 'pandas, ast, re'. Reason: Can't find a pure Python 3 Wheel for package(s) 'pandas, ast, re'.See: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#micropip-can-t-find-a-pure-python-wheel for more information."

I've tried placing my config in head tags and in a separate file as well linking directly to Python wheels, but all I get are errors. I've seen other projects using Pandas with this exact config pattern and they work. What am I doing wrong?

The complete code for my site [is here](https://1a3cf5e3-4254-4ddd-8baf-2d4d4c34ed70.pyscriptapps.com/6cbb7866-b7ab-4380-a1ad-8a50ffdec7ba/latest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ast` and `re` are in the standard library, and so don’t need to be installed via `packages`. You can think of the `packages` key as equivalent as the list of things you’d use pip to install - in this case, just pandas.